# Why does Usui wear glasses at home?

Tags: maid-sama

Usui wears glasses when he is at home, but at school he doesn't wear them. Hence, either he is wearing contacts at school, or he doesn't really need vision aid but he likes wearing glasses at home for some reason. Why does he choose to wear glasses at home, but not at school?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that he has contacts but doesn't want to wear them at home, but I don't think it was ever addressed.

Comment: contacts are the most likely explanation.  some people find them bothersome so he may be more comfortable taking them out when he is not in public.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usui-kun, wears contacts at school and glasses at home. Most probably, this shows how Usui is different from school and from the comfort of his own home. Revealing the real Usui when he is out of everyone's sight. ^^

Comment: What do you mean by *different* at school and at home? Does he prefer to look geek at home and wants to be cool at school? Do you have any basis for this? Probably in manga? :P :D :)

Comment: no.. actually, it was my own opinion :) I read the manga, but I couldn't remember if Usui reveals the reason why he wears his glasses out of school. Probably, the author or the writer just wants to show that usui has different sides to show. The usui one he would show in public and the REAL usui.

Comment: You have a point. And probably it also shows that Usui, the cool guy at school can also be lazy. I mean, he also gets lazy to put on the contacts and put on eyeglasses instead. And probably he's nearsighted. :P

Answer (score -1):

In the question/answer segments Hiro Fujiwara sometimes adds at the ends of chapters, Usui said that he thinks he has 20/100 vision in one eye and 20/30 in the other eye. It was also confirmed he wore contacts at school.

Comment: Hi, this looks like a good starting point for an answer, and it would be better if you could add the specific chapter number as an official reference. Thanks!